# Why doesn't adding a backslash in front of an f-string make it an escape sequence

Tags: python

I wanted to know why this:

```
a = '\nabc'

print(a)
```

gives:

```
abc
```

and why does this:

```
a = 'n abc'
a = f'\{a}'

print(a)
```

gives:

```
\n abc
```

instead of this:

```
abc
```

and how can I make this:

```
a = 'n abc'
a = f'\{a}'

print(a)
```

gives:

```
abc
```

instead of:

```
\n abc
```

Please help!

Comment: Because '\n' is a single character in its own right. Why not use `a = '\n abc'` then `a=f'{a}'`?

Comment: Could you please explain why you need this? The reason, why this is happening is because in the second case `\\` is interpreted literally as a backslash and in the first case as the start of the escape sequence. That's just how python interprets this.

Comment: @Yevhen Kuzmovych It's not just to add a \ in front of an 'n', I just wanted to express my problem in an easier way. and thank you! and do I have a solution for it

Comment: "\n" is used to represent the new line character. All encoding schemes have this character, but since its supposed to read as a new line, it can't really be typed in. Most programming languages then interpret the backslash as the start of an escape sequence and the next letter indicating which escape to use. When you split the backlash from the n, as above, python is interpreting that as two separate characters because anything could have followed that backslash. Since its interpreted as two characters, it will not be used as a new line character. I would suggest using a="abc" and f"\n{a}".

Comment: For the same reason that `'\' + 'n'` doesn't create a newline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t.  If at some point in your program your statement is

```
a = f'\{a}'

print(a)
```

then no value of `a` can make this print a newline first.

The reason is that the line `a= f'\{a}'` prepends a backslash to the contents of the string `a`.  To prepend a newline you would need to write this: `a = f'\n{a}'`.

You see, the `\` is a character and the `\n` is a character as well.  It’s *one* character, not two.  The `\n` is a notation in source code to name one single character, namely the newline character.  So adding a `\` to anything will not create a newline.

Your problem sounds very much like an A/B problem in which you ask for A because you want to achieve B and think that A is the correct way.  It probably isn’t in your case.  I propose to tell us why you want to do this, then probably we can give you a much more helpful advice than my initial “You can’t”.

EDIT: As it turns out, you have `"U00000D05"` in a variable and want to create (and print) the unicode character of that number:

```
print(chr(int(s[1:], 16)))
```

The `int(x, 16)` converts a string of hex digits into an int.  `chr()` then converts the int to a unicode character.

Btw, your original approach was to use the Python parser to create the character.  This also is possible but not recommended (the way given above is the straight forward one, it's safe and fast).  To use the parser nevertheless use this:

```
s = "U00000D05"
print(eval('"\\' + s + '"'))
```

Here you build a string starting and ending with a doublequote a which contains `\U00000D02` between them (so the string’s contents is `"\U00000D02"`), and this is given to `eval()` which calls the Python parser for a value.

But as I said, this is not the recommended way to do it.  With a malicious value in `s` this even bears a security risk.  Don't use `eval()` if you don't know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I have a letter's Unicode as 'U00000D05' in a variable so I want to print that letter as അ (I mean as that letter instead of that code) how can I do that

Comment: There you go.  `chr(0xd05)`.   Or like this:  `s = 'U00000D05'; print(chr(int(s[1:], 16)))`

Comment: Can I like do it with that variable, like chr(variable_name)

Comment: Great. + for a safe approach `'unicode-escape'` and `'raw-unicode-escape'` encodings can be used which I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69134543/13944524).

Answer (score 1):

For the reason why you saw that behavior you can see @Alfe's answer.

For solution there are two encodings that can help you if you don't want to use `eval` or `exec` which is do not recommended. `'raw-unicode-escape'` and `'unicode-escape'`

```
a = 'n abc'
a = f'\{a}'

print(a.encode('raw-unicode-escape').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

Comment: This was what I really wanted!

Answer (score 0):

**\n** is the escape code for a new line. As soon as it reads **\n** it breaks anything after into a new line.

When you use it as `string = f'\{variable}'` you're passing formatted text so the slash is being read as part of the string.

To achieve what you're probably asking you want to use `string = f'\n{variable}'`

See [these examples of using escape codes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp)